# MojoFailureException in Eclipse project

Tags: java, maven, jsweet

I'm using Ecplise for a Java project with Maven and Jsweet.
In my workspace I've got two projects: one of the back-end with the servlets and one of the front-end.
When I tried to compile only the front end to generate js files for html pages I don't had any problem.
I've added the back-end project to the required project of the front-end project but I had this error. 
What does it mean? How can fix it?

I'm already compiling with plugin `clean install`.

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jsweet:jsweet-maven-plugin:2.3.0-SNAPSHOT:jsweet (generate-js) on project jsweet-quickstart: transpilation failed
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: transpilation failed
    at org.jsweet.AbstractJSweetMojo.transpile(AbstractJSweetMojo.java:541)
    at org.jsweet.JSweetMojo.execute(JSweetMojo.java:43)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: transpilation failed with 3 error(s) and 0 warning(s)
    at org.jsweet.AbstractJSweetMojo.transpile(AbstractJSweetMojo.java:526)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: As the error message says jsweet failed. You should get more Informations before this stacktrace.

Comment: `transpilation failed with 3 error(s) and 0 warning(s)`...

Comment: Check this link: https://github.com/cincheo/jsweet/issues/147